# Classes not updating with setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know where my logic is flawed. I have a day planner that is supposed to update the color of the time block every hour. The console.log(hour) starts logging the next hour when it arrives, so why doesn't my ifFunction change the classes of the time block? Any help is much appreciated.

I omitted some if else statements for the sake of brevity.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    update = function () {
        var currentDay = $("#currentDay")
        var date = moment(new Date())
        currentDay.html(date.format("dddd, MMMM Do"));
        var d = new Date();
        var hour = d.getHours();
        console.log(d);
        console.log(hour);
    ifFunction = function() {
        if (hour < 9) {
            $("#time1").addClass("future");
            $("#time2").addClass("future");
            $("#time3").addClass("future");
            $("#time4").addClass("future");
            $("#time5").addClass("future");
            $("#time6").addClass("future");
            $("#time7").addClass("future");
            $("#time8").addClass("future");
            $("#time9").addClass("future");
        }
        else if (hour > 17) {
            $("#time1").addClass("past");
            $("#time2").addClass("past");
            $("#time3").addClass("past");
            $("#time4").addClass("past");
            $("#time5").addClass("past");
            $("#time6").addClass("past");
            $("#time7").addClass("past");
            $("#time8").addClass("past");
            $("#time9").addClass("past");
        }
        else if (hour === 17) {
            $("#time1").addClass("past");
            $("#time2").addClass("past");
            $("#time3").addClass("past");
            $("#time4").addClass("past");
            $("#time5").addClass("past");
            $("#time6").addClass("past");
            $("#time7").addClass("past");
            $("#time8").addClass("past");
            $("#time9").addClass("present");
    }
    }
    
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000);
    ifFunction();
    setInterval(ifFunction, 1000);
```

Comment: Add a `console.log("update")` to the update function and similar for ifFunction (different text of course) and see what order they are running in.  `setInterval` isn't intended to be 100% accurate and it may be that ifFunction is running first in some cases.  I recommend you add `ifFunction()` to the end of `update()` and only have a single `setInterval()`

Answer (score 0):

For me it will be easier to separate the functions

- Combine selectors `$('selector1 , selector2 .....')`
- Make shorthand `if/else` `() ? :`  to get the wanted classes

---

Try the next code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    update = function () {
        var currentDay = $("#currentDay")
        var date = moment(new Date())
        currentDay.html(date.format("dddd, MMMM Do"));
        var d = new Date();
        var hour = d.getHours();
        console.log(d);
        console.log(hour);
        ifFunction(hour);
    }
    ifFunction = function(hour) {
        var TheClass = hour < 9 ? 'future' : hour > 17 ? 'past' : hour === 17 ? 'past' : '';
        var ThePresent = TheClass == 'past' && hour === 17 ? "present" : TheClass;
            console.log(TheClass , ThePresent);
            $("#time1 , #time2 , #time3 , #time4 , #time5 , #time6 , #time7 , #time8").removeClass('future past present').addClass(TheClass);
            $("#time9").removeClass('future past present').addClass(ThePresent);
    }
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000);
});
```

Code in action *Change hour with the number you want you should get the correct classes on console*

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    update = function () {
        var currentDay = $("#currentDay")
        //var date = moment(new Date())
        //currentDay.html(date.format("dddd, MMMM Do"));
        //var d = new Date();
        var hour = 17; //d.getHours();
        //console.log(d);
        console.log(hour);
        ifFunction(hour);
    }
    ifFunction = function(hour) {
        var TheClass = hour < 9 ? 'future' : hour > 17 ? 'past' : hour === 17 ? 'past' : '';
        var ThePresent = TheClass == 'past' && hour === 17 ? "present" : TheClass;
            console.log(TheClass , ThePresent);
            $("#time1 , #time2 , #time3 , #time4 , #time5 , #time6 , #time7 , #time8").removeClass('future past present').addClass(TheClass);
            $("#time9").removeClass('future past present').addClass(ThePresent);
    }
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Notes:**

- In your code the `ifFunction` is under the `update` function that means if you try to run it like `ifFunction()` it will gives you an error .. And like @freedomn-m said its enough to have a single `setInterval` with the `update` function
- Also you need to remove the classes using `removeClass()` before append the new one